# Compare files/folders across servers

Tags: unix

We have two Unix servers, spread across two countries. These servers hold our software repository (scripts, binaries, documents etc). I am looking for a simple way to keep these servers in sync ideally using a script. `rsync` and `nfs` are not an option.

I'd like to capture the listing of `server1` and `server2` (along with files + folders) and then compare them using a script to then decide which files to copy.

Comment: Why is `rsync` not an option? It's pretty well-suited for the task.

Comment: @ewwhite `rsync` is perfectly suited for this task. Perhaps the issue is not understanding how remote authentication with `rsync` would work?

Comment: silent ssh is blocked. The servers are behind a few firewalls. In fact, we can think of these two servers as separate entities with no form of communication allowed between them.

Comment: If the servers are not connected how are you going to compare those listings?

Comment: Are you talking about the entire filesystem or just your software repository? If it's just your software, putting that software repository in a VCS would solve this problem.  You just need to transfer the git repo on to each box the same way you would transfer the script and then do a `git clone`.

Answer (score 1):

If there is a third machine to act as mediator, you could script around pulling the files (using SCP or the like) and pulling metadata (remotely invoking the "stat" command) and making the decision, then pushing whichever version is more "right" to the "losing" machine. Not pretty, but it would do the job.

Answer (score 0):

You can perform the `rsync` algorithm manually.  The [librsync](https://github.com/librsync/librsync) library includes an `rdiff` CLI tool ([documentation](http://librsync.sourcefrog.net/doc/rdiff.html)) that simply wraps the `librsync` functions to make them usable manually.

Efficiently transfer a file from A to B you can follow this procedure:

1. In machine B create a 'signature' file that describes what is already there
2. In machine A use the signature file and the original source to create a 'patch' file containing the instructions and data to transform the file at B to finish with the file at C.
3. Back in machine B, apply the patch and it will transform the file used as reference into the 'original' file scanned at machine A.